# Inequality $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\cos(kx) < -\frac{1}{\epsilon}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\sin(kx)\right|$ - Miklos Schweitzer

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Prove that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a positive integer $n$ and positive numbers $a_{1},...,a_{n}$  such that for every $\epsilon < x < 2\pi - \epsilon$ we have:
>
> $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\cos(kx) < -\frac{1}{\epsilon}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\sin(kx)\right|$

This problem is from Miklos Schweitzer Competition 2000.
I tried to consider the case when $a_{1}=...=a_{n}=1$.
I also tried to find polynomials such that $\displaystyle p(x) \leq -\frac{|p(\sqrt{1-x^2})|}{\epsilon}$ for all $x \in [-1,1]-[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ but I couldn't make any progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex function
$$
f(z)
= \left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^2-1=\frac{4z}{(1-z)^2}
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty 4kz^2
$$ 
maps the unit disk to the entire plane except for the ray $(-\infty,-1)$. The image of the circle of radius $r<1$ is some curve like in the picture. If $1-r$ is sufficiently small then the green arc will be in the angle domain $|\mathrm{arg}\,f-\pi|<\epsilon$.

[image]

Now we can take the first $n$ terms from the power series of $f$ along the circle. Due the uniform convergence, for sufficiently large $n$, this Taylor polynomial will satisfy the required property; this means
$$
a_k = 4k\cdot r^k
$$
with $1-r$ is small enough, and then $n$ is large enough, 
is a possible construction.

Comment: Thank you! A very beautiful problem with an even more beautiful solution.